# Usage of the word "ineffective"

Tags: adjectives

Is it possible to use the word “ineffective” referring to people as is written in the following sentence?  (Many thanks for the primary responses to this question, particularly
MarcInManhattan. I edited to clarify my inquiry, adding some source URLs. 15/06/2022, 3:18 GMT)

> Gun-rights groups and Republicans counter that their opponents are ineffective because the Second Amendment is a bedrock American principle.

Collins Cobuid and McMillan Dictionaries show the word ineffective takes something, not a person, as its subject when it is used predicate.

Is it more appropriate to write “any argument against gun rights supported by their opponents is ineffective”? If it is, the writer of this sentence implicitly suggests that the defiance of the gun-rights groups does not sound as acceptable as they insist, since they fail to use the word correctly.

Here is the URL for the quoted sentence: https://www.wsj.com/articles/gun-control-groups-are-growing-in-numbers-while-hitting-a-federal-wall-11653657821?mod=Searchresults_pos1&page=1

Here are the URLS for the word in the dictionaries:
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ineffective
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ineffective

Comment: I guess "opponents are ineffective" suggest their *arguments* are ineffective - since the groups insist the Second Amendment's right of a *militia* belongs to a militia of one.

Comment: Do you have more context? Like a link?

Comment: "Their opponents" would presumably be gun-control advocates. In that case, their claims would be for gun controls, not against them.

Comment: You're supposed to show what you found when you did some basic research (e.g. consult a dictionary) and explain where you got stuck in figuring this out.

Comment: Both people and things can be ineffective. It all depend on the context whether that use is appropriate. People are ineffective at -doing- things, whereas things are ineffective at ... well, affecting things. So a person is ineffective in general, but a thing is ineffective for a specific purpose. (A vice president is not very effective...they can't get the project running or profits to rise. A hammer is ineffective at raking up leaves.) So in your sentence, it feels like something is missing by just saying 'the opponents are ineffective'). Maybe context would help?

Comment: Plenty of uses with people in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ineffective) e.g. "the loss leading auditors are also spectacularly ineffective".